# how can I set visible back to true in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to hide a dropdown box:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="test1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsTestType" CssClass="maptest1" visible="false"
    DataValueField="test_code" DataTextField="test_desc" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

Somehow I try to show this dropdown by using the following code, but this is just not working for me. Anyone know why?

```
$("#test1").show();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using ASP.NET's `visible="false"` property will set the `visibility` attribute  where as I think when you call `show()` in jQuery it modifies the `display` attribute of the CSS style.

So doing the latter won't rectify the former.

You need to do this:

```
$("#test1").attr("visibility", "visible");
```

Comment: @Jin Youn, Why you choose this as answer? Did you try it? It does not work, the right answer is JohnP answer.

Comment: @Amir976 Take a look at the first part of JohnP's answer. Ring a bell at all? It does work and it obviously worked nicely for Jin. Why would he accept an answer that doesn't work?

Comment: author probably ment .css

Comment: Yeah I'm sure they did. I mean, they didn't tag it with `css`, the question didn't explicitly state "I want to do this in CSS only", _and_ they accepted the answer which used Jquery. ;)

Comment: why is this answer accepted , you cannot modify asp 'visible' attribute from browser as it is set on server. Please dont accept answers like this it misguides new users.

Comment: @GonchuGolu perhaps you can tell me what jQuery has got to do with server-side processing? The OP asked about jQuery, which is client-side. The answer is also 4 years old (yup, 4 whole years. Quite a while eh?), which means things might have changed since the original question was answered. Feel free to invest time in a better answer, instead of complaining about existing ones, so people can learn and upvote. Perhaps then your karma will hit triple digits.

Comment: @OJ dropdown in question is an asp.net server control and for server controls you cannot modify visible property on client side.

Comment: He wanted to hide it in the browser. Yes it's an ASP.NET control, he wasn't asking for server-side code, he was asking for client-side visibility toggling. And yes, this code does work, it does hide the element in the browser. Drop it and move on mate.

Comment: the question does not specify the use of ASP.NET's visible attribute, so this answer is making a false assumption. You're right that jQuery show() sets the css display attribute, so that would not effect the rendered output if the original question HAD specified the use ASP.NET's visible attribute. It would also be worth noting that css visibility and display effect layout differently. visibilty will still occupy the space of that element in the page, whereas display will not. Unfortunately terminology like 'hide the element in the browser' contains misleading ambiguities.

Comment: this doesn't make a sense !

Comment: in jquery , i didnt find asp.net control which is visble= false, than,how jquery will finding this "test1" control?

Answer (score 60):

Depends on how you hid it.

If you used the CSS `visibility` value then

```
$('#test1').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

If you used CSS `display'

```
$('#test1').css('display', 'block'); //or inline or any of the other combos
```

You might even have made it opacity = 0

```
$('#test1').css('opacity', '1');
```

Answer (score 6):

Depends, if i remember correctly i think asp.net won't render the html object out when you set visible to false.

If you want to be able to control it from the client side, then you better just include the css value to set it invisible rather than using visible =false.

Comment: This is what I ran into.  If you set it visible=false in the code behind.  There is no element for jQuery to work on in the client side.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the visible="false" attribute and add a CSS class that is not visible by default.
Then you should be able to reference the dropdown by the correct id, for example:

```
$("#ctl00_cphTest_test1").show();
```

Above ID you should serach for in the source of the rendered page in your browser.

Answer (score 3):

How you made it invisible? Try different approach. Use

```
$("#test1").css('display','none');
```

When you want to hide that element, and then use

```
$("#test1").css('display','block');
```

When you wnat to show it.

Or just move these styles into a class and add/remove class.

Comment: He has set the `Visible` property to `false` using the UI designer. You can't see it unless you scroll horizontally in the code snippet.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with styles. It's to do with the `visibility` attribute. the `show()` method does what you've suggested.

Comment: It has to do with how IIS renders the page. It doesn't map everything over to the CSS attributes you would expect. Are you certain it's visibility:hidden and not display:none?

Comment: @Tieson T. Ah, I didn't see that. @OJ My bad, didn't see that visible attribute. But I believe that saying "doesn't have anything to do with styles" isn't correct. Visibility is an style attribute anyway, right?

Comment: Oh. Heh. I thought your comment was in reference to my comment. Yes, it is, although I thought I remember it not being supported as well. Have to check that though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `style="display:none"` in your dropdown list tag and in jquery use the following to display and hide.

```
$("#yourdropdownid").css('display', 'inline');
```

OR

```
$("#yourdropdownid").css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful with setting the `display` of the element to block. Different elements have the standard display as different things. For example setting display to block for a table row in firefox causes the width of the cells to be incorrect.

Is the name of the element actually test1. I know that .NET can add extra things onto the start or end. The best way to find out if your selector is working properly is by doing this.

```
alert($('#text1').length);
```

You might just need to remove the visibility attribute

```
$('#text1').removeAttr('visibility');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since you are using ASP.NET controls with a `runat` attribute, the ID of the control is not actually "test1". It's "test1" with a long string attached to it.